# How to install DWSScript

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dwscript

I am having trouble installing DWSScript component. I am using Delphi XE2 and when I try to compile the dwsLibRuntime.dpk I get an error ( Array type required ). I am using the latest DWScript source pulled from the project's svn repo.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 toStr:=TStringListCracker(sl).FList[i].FString; //produces error
 System.MonitorExit(sl);
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i mentioned that i am using delphi xe 2 ;) what can i do in this case ?

Comment: yep i have the last version ...

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling with XE2? I can see that the implementation of `TStringList` has changed (certainly between 2010 and XE2) in a way that would explain that error.

Comment: As a complete aside, does anyone know why this code feels the need to poke around with the private implementation details of `TStringList`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes i am pretty shure i know what compiler i am using :)

Comment: Have a read of the implementation of `TStringList` in your XE2 RTL source code and you'll see why I am puzzled.

Comment: @David: it's a speed optimization, it removes a complex call, a range check, an UStrAsg and accompanying bus lock from a critical section, along with an implicit exception frame in UnifyAssignString (used to guard the return value of the Get) and reduce register pressure in UnifyAssignString. Speedup is a few percent points in single-threaded situations up to 20-30% in some heavily multi-threaded scenarios. Just look at the code in the CPU view between the cracker-hack and the "toStr:=sl[i]" variant.

Comment: @Eric Thanks. Any idea why opc0de is getting this error? Seems pretty inexplicable to me.

Comment: @David: his source seems out of date, the Monitor isn't used there and was replaced in february 2011.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not using the latest version, the monitor isn't used anymore (due to contention bugs in the RTL implementation), the second line should read as "sl.FLock.Leave;".
You're likely on a pre-Delphi XE2 version, as the Monitor was dropped in february 2011.

http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/source/browse/trunk/Source/dwsUtils.pas#475

Make sure you're on the head/trunk, or Delphi isn't pointed to a different directory than the one updated by your SVN client.

Comment: is there any link to an Installation guide for DWS? I have no idea how to compile lets say the HTTP.sys Server. How do I have to configure the IDE to compile DWS Projects?

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you downloaded the newest version from the [main source](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/downloads/list), because DWScript 2.3 preview 1 is now available.

Then you must notice on this [page](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/source/list) that everyday you have changes on DWScript, so check where is the error (in which unit), then go to the [source code page](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk) to take the most recent units.

Personally, it happened to me, and after I fixed some changes, it worked fine.

Comment: You can also use an SVN client (the one built in Delphi, or Tortoise SVN) to keep your files up to date.