# DWScript Install

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dwscript

I'm trying to install DWScript in XE2 and I seem to be struggling. I can't find any up to date installation instructions, and the older instructions I did find no longer seems applicable.

I've tried both head from the svn repository, and also one of the previous releases and haven't had much luck with either.

I've added the source directory to my library path.

When I opened dwsLib originally I had a TdwsUnit not found message, although it appears to compile. Both dwsLibDesignOnly and dwsLibRuntime.dpk have an error about dwsCodeGen which is missing, and it appears there is a whole JSCodeGen directory in Libraries which doesn't exist but should.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9885335/62576) has a couple of answers that might help (posted just a few months ago, and XE2 specific). Also, when you say "have an error", it's helpful if you mention what the specific error is (including the exact error message). By itself, "an error" is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I did take a look at that question before posting. I've updated my question, but essentially the specific error is that the dwsCodeGen file doesn't exist. There appears to be a missing directory (JSCodeGen) which should contain that file and several others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CodeGen is no longer maintained in the SVN, and the dpks were a bit out of date (updated now). You can just remove the units/classes it doesn't find from the .dpk

For further details on the CodeGen see http://delphitools.info/2012/05/18/from-op4js-to-smart-mobile-studio/
The last open-source version can be found in r1462 of the SVN.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'm up to date now and everything installs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try revision r1462.
After that revision project owner decide to close source for JavaScript CodeGen and contunue development only for MobileStudio product.